# Unity bluetooth communication - implementation

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, unity-game-engine, 32feet

So I have read and tried about everything in order to start a simple bluetooth listener in Unity but with no luck. And couldn't find anyone who managed this.

The main issue is this socket exception:

"SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used."

Has anyone successfully implemented bluetooth communication in Unity?

P.S. 
I also tried the 32feet library but it gives the same exception when trying to create a new bluetooth listener :

```
    Guid mUUID = new Guid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    BluetoothListener blueListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
```

Comment: What address do you use? Are you sure it's not malformed and the right address family?

Comment: the bluetooth device on my computer has the mac address: C8FF28873651